# Es una buena práctica devolver referencias a un array o se debe modificar el propio array

Tags: java, array, buenas-prácticas

Tengo un array de productos y quiero rebajar los que sean más caros de 200 €. Si hago un método que obtenga un nuevo array con referencias al original puedo modificarlo, modificando también el original. ¿Sería la forma correcta de proceder?
Pongo un código de ejemplo:

```
public class Producto {
private final String ID;
private final String descripcion;
private int precio;


public Producto(String ID, String descripcion, int precio) {
    this.ID = ID;
    this.descripcion = descripcion;
    this.precio = precio;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ID=" + ID + " - " + descripcion + " - " + precio + '€';
}

public String getID() {
    return ID;
}

public String getDescripcion() {
    return descripcion;
}

public int getPrecio() {
    return precio;
}

public void setPrecio(int precio) {
    this.precio = precio;
}
}
```

Y la clase que lo prueba:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

/*Dado un array de Productos (ID, Descripción, Precio en euros enteros)

Hacer las siguientes operaciones:

Mostrar (obtener) los productos más caros que un precio dado
Rebajar los productos más caros que un precio dado un tanto por ciento dado (
Black Friday: Todo lo que supere 200 €, lo rebajamos un 20%)
Mostrar los productos ordenados por ID, por precio y por Descripción
(por precio ascendente y descendente)
*/
public class Principal {
public static Producto[] productosPrecioMinimo(int precioMinimo,Producto[] lista){
    Producto[] salida=new Producto[lista.length];
    int indiceInsercionSalida=0;
    for (Producto p :
            lista) {
        if (p.getPrecio() > precioMinimo) {
            salida[indiceInsercionSalida++]=p;
        }
        }
        return Arrays.copyOf(salida,indiceInsercionSalida);
}

public static String cadenaListadoProductos(Producto[] lista){
    String salida="";
    for (Producto p :
            lista) {
        salida+=p+"\n";
    }
    return salida;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Producto[] lista={
            new Producto("AA","Disco Duro",200),
            new Producto("BB","Monitor",100),
            new Producto("CC","Tarjeta de Red",300),
            new Producto("DD","Impresora",200),
            new Producto("EE","Portátil",700),
            new Producto("FF","Proyector",150),
            new Producto("GG","Router Wifi",60),

    };

    System.out.println(cadenaListadoProductos(lista));
    System.out.println("--------------------");
    Producto[] caros=productosPrecioMinimo(200,lista);
    System.out.println(cadenaListadoProductos(caros));
    caros[0].setPrecio(1000);
    System.out.println("-------------------");
    System.out.println(cadenaListadoProductos(lista));

}

}
```

Muchas gracias por las respuestas

Comment: Hola Miguel, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Las preguntas de *buenas prácticas* se parecen mucho a preguntas de opinion y es motivo de cierre... Mira [ask] y [help] para ver el tipo de preguntas válidas en el sitio. 
Un saludo.

Comment: Vale. La traduciré y la mandaré a code review. Gracias